# SQLCMD is appending newline and "1" in the query results

Tags: sql, ksh, sqlcmd

I am calling sqlcmd utility from ksh script to retrieve dummy record and store it in a variable

```
MY_VAR=`sqlcmd -S server,port -U username -P password -d dbname -h -1 -W -q "SET NOCOUNT ON; select 'dummy';"`
```

I'm expecting `MY_VAR` to contain "dummy" as it is the row returned from the query, also `-h -1` is used to remove the header and `-W` to remove the trailing spaces. But instead, the output is

```
dummy
1
```

I don't know where 1 is coming. I'm firing the query itself and its correctly giving me "dummy" as result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use the uppercase `-Q`. And you can skip both ; I think.

```
> SQLCMD.EXE -E -S .\SQLEXPRESS -W -h -1 -Q "SET NOCOUNT ON select 'dummy'"
dummy
```